# Do I need to create different instances of forms

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a SinupForm in my controller that I pass to signup view

object SignUpController extends Controller {

```
private val signUpForm = Form(
    tuple(
        "email" -> nonEmptyText.verifying(
        "email already exists",
        emailString => Accounts.findBy(emailString).isEmpty),
        "full_name" -> nonEmptyText,
        "password" -> text(minLength = 6)
))

def signup = Action {
    Ok(views.html.signup(signUpForm))
}
```

}

Because I am new to Play framework, I am confused. Suppose 10 requests comes at a time for signup, in that case do I need to pass separate form instances to each requests ?

Answer (score 4):

No you don't. The `signUpForm` is actually immutable and it is a template of how the data should be binded into an object.

You can use it safely and do not worry about concurrent requests

Comment: thanks serejja, I thought so, but wanted to confirm.